# How do I make a Java application I made run as a deamon?

Tags: boot, java, script

I have a Java Application is going to be my Discord Server's bot.

How do I make this application run as a daemon on a Raspberry Pi, it uses the latest version of Raspbian and the Java application runs off a jar file, though it does require an env variable to set its Spring profile.

How can I make the application run as a Deamon, Plus I need it to have commands to stop and start, as I going to hook up a Jenkins Build server to stop the service, and then restart it with the new version it built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you make any program run as a daemon regardless of the language it has been written in!

Read the documentation for `systemd`. At a minimum, you will have to create something like `/etc/systemd/system/yourprogram.service`. There are way too many options that you need to set depending on exactly what your program does. In all likelihood, all the defaults will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Services are managed by **systemd**. Just start with a simple Unit file:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --full --force edit myjar.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Descrition=My jar service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Environment="ENV_VAR_FOR_JAR=something"
ExecStart=/absolute/path/to/myprogram.jar

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To manage the service just use:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl start|stop|restart myjar.service
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --full edit myjar.service   # edit the Unit again
rpi ~$ systemctl status myjar.service
```

If you want to start the service at boot up, then do

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable myjar.service
```

If this doesn't run on the first attempt (very likely) then ask again so we can look what other special settings your program needs. Have a look at `man systemd.exec` for some options.